# Adding event handlers to dynamically added elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following example page appends three `<button>` tags based on the `foo` object, and when clicked, I expect them to output the values in `foo`. For example, clicking on the button with ID `btn1`, I expect to get the output `Title:baz, ID:7198`. However, every button press outputs `Title:whizbang, ID:7119`.

I believe the culprit is in the event handler for the buttons (`$("#btn" + i).click(function()`), but I'm not sure. I've stepped through it and when clicked, the value of `i` is 2, no matter which button is pressed.

How do I accomplish the behavior I am looking for? jQuery is not a requirement, but what I happen to be using.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript'>
var foo = {
  "foo": [
      {
          "title":"bar",
          "id":7826
      },
      {
          "title":"baz", 
          "id":7198
      }, 
      {
          "title":"whizbang", 
          "id":7119
      }
  ]
};
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() { 
  for (i in foo.foo) { 
      $("#content").append("<button type='button' id='btn" + i + "'>" + foo.foo[i].title + "</button>"); 
      $("#btn" + i).click(function() { 
          $("#result").append("<p>Title:" + foo.foo[i].title + ", ID:" + foo.foo[i].id + "</p>"); 
      }); 
  }
}); 

</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id='content' />
  <div id='result' />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why not add a class to them and write one event of class selector

Comment: You shouldn't use for in loops to iterate over arrays. Use the forEach method or a conditional increment for loop.

Comment: @SimpleJ thanks for the tip about `forEach`, it did exactly what I needed, if you want to write up a simple answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[fiddle showing this solution working](http://jsfiddle.net/BAHDh/)

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
     for (var i = 0; i < foo.foo.length; i++) { 
         $("#content").append("<button type='button' class='btn' data-btnid='"+i+"'>" + foo.foo[i].title + "</button>"); 
     }

     $("#content").on("click", ".btn", function() {
         var btnid = $(this).attr("data-btnid");
         $("#result").append("<p>Title:" + foo.foo[btnid].title + ", ID:" + foo.foo[btnid].id + "</p>"); 
     });
});
```

Like others have said, you should change your loop. Other than that these are the changes I made:

- All your buttons have the same behavior, so give them the same class rather than an id
- put the button id in a custom attribute (`data-btnid`). Custom attributes start with `data-`.
- For actually getting the behavior you want, you have to dynamically bind the click event. Essentially you use a selector to get the parent, in your case it's `$("#content")`, and bind a click event to children with the class `btn`. Then it accesses the button that was clicked's custom attribute `data-btnid` to get the id which is the index of the information in your array.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe here is need to save value of var i for each iteration, for example, in closure: put function which you pass as argument in click(..) in wrapper function by this way:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    for (i in foo.foo) { 
        $("#content").append("<button type='button' id='btn" + i + "'>" + foo.foo[i].title + "</button>"); 
        $("#btn" + i).click((function(i){
            function() { 
                $("#result").append("<p>Title:" + foo.foo[i].title + ", ID:" + foo.foo[i].id + "</p>"); 
            }
        })(i)); 
    }
});
```